# How to change Drupal's ajax gif loader

Tags: drupal, loader, gif

I want to change Drupal's (6) ajax gif loader without having to change the gif itself nor tampering with core css files... but by overriding it from my theme's css.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean `misc/throbber.gif` loader, you can simply override it in your stylesheets using `html.js input.form-autocomplete` and  `.ahah-progress .throbber` css classes

Comment: See, I have already overriden `html.js a.views-throbbing` and `html.js span.views-throbbing`, which works in views... that I knew, there are plenty of css selectors to modify, I was hoping for a _"bind them all"_ solution...

Comment: not so much selectors actually, only 2 for `misc/throbber.gif`, 1 for `status-active.gif`